# Can't found personal application of Microsoft Teams Toolkit when I sideload it in Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

Went through all of the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/build-your-first-app/build-and-run and repeated it for the letter.
I could run the application Hello World on https://localhost:3000/Tab, but when I tried to **sideload in the Teams**, there was a problem.

I followed step by step what we need to do for sideloading the app in Teams and I gave the permission to upload personal application in Teams using my admin account. But when I opened the https://localhost:3000/Tab and click the bouton add for installing this app in Teams, Teams said: there is a problem.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please send a screenshot, and upload your manifest (you can hide IDs inside there, but it's important to see some of your settings that could affect this)

Comment: I'm sorry for the late. But in fact, it's the first time that I use StackOverflow for asking question, and when I tried to upload some screenshot, it didn't allow. The problem is when I try to open the personal application using the debugger with proposed by Teams Toolkit, we could see a screen which ask me to add Application in my Teams. Then I opened the localhost:3000 like the documentations said. In the end, i click on add for sideloading my app. But there is always some problem when I do like that. Fortunately, i solved this problem by installing directly app in App studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's great that your issue got resolved by installing the app directly through App Studio.
But mostly there is some permission which might be missing and which was stopping you from sideloading the app.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In fact, I don't know why it dosen't work when I asked the question. But once I installed the app directly from the App Studio, it works everytime like in the documentation when I need to sideload some application in Teams. It means I can add directly the app in Teams with the pop-up that I got by running the "Debug Teams". Anyway, thans for your anwser.